# In Unity Load another scene when the button is clicked on the first scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created two scenes in unity of which I would like to load scene 2 If the button1 on scene one is clicked. I've been googling this issue,reading unity documentation but I only find this

```
   Application.LoadLevel("SceneTwo");
```

I've tried to use this but my scene two just load without me clicking the button on the First scene.
Here is my code For the First scene at the moment

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class first : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

            Application.LoadLevel("MiniGame");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Application.LoadLevel("MiniGame");
    }
}
```

I've linked this script with the button on my First screen And "MiniGame" is the second scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create GUI Button.
2. Write public function script for level changing. As in the following example.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class first : MonoBehaviour 
   {
       public void GoToLevel(string level)
       {
           Application.LoadLevel (level);
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Set your GUI Button's OnClick method. I used my script in canvas, you can use in any object.
   [image: For Example]

Also you can watch [unity scene selection tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-a-scene-menu)

Answer (score 2):

`Application.LoadLevel (level);` is obsolete.

Could use `SceneManager.LoadScene()`instead.

Answer (score -1):

This is totally wrong usage of the [Application.LoadLevel() functionality](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html). But this is not the only problem here. [Start()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) in Unity scripting is called once on the creation of the object which has this script attached to it. Update() is called every frame, which means that right now you are asking unity to load the 2nd level of yours thousands of times until it "crashes" i assume.

In order to fix this functionality you should create a clickable object by attaching this script to the object you want to click

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class first : MonoBehaviour 
 {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {

 }
 void Update () 
 {

 }

 void OnMouseDown()
 {
   // this object was clicked - do something
 Application.LoadLevel("MiniGame");
 }
```

And of course you will need to add a collider to the object you are trying to click

Comment: i tried to update ny script but when I click the button nothing is happening.

Comment: did you add a collider on the object? If you want please update your question with more details on what you are trying to achieve.